# Pushing unique elements in vector (indexOf())

Tags: javascript, arrays, unique

this weekend i was trying to do some searching in a file and store at the array the unique values i got from the match string. I managed to do this but when i was looking here in i found one solution with indexOf() and tried to do the logic like below:

```
router.post('/getIdDisciplina', function(req, res, next){


var idDisc = req.body.IdDisciplina;
  idDisc = idDisc.toUpperCase();
  var arrayRes = [];
  for (let i = 0; i < jsonBD.relacao.length; i++)
  {
    if(jsonBD.relacao[i].disciplina == idDisc){
      if(arrayRes.indexOf(jsonBD.relacao[i].sala) === -1); //this should have done the 'MAGIC'
      {
        arrayRes.push(jsonBD.relacao[i].sala);
      }
    }
  }
  let new_array = Array.from(new Set(arrayRes));
});
```

My file is in .JSON and i receive the input from a POST form, basically i loop the file (small data, just to write some code with it) and see if it's a match, then see if is already in the array and push it or not, but the code fails to do that.

The last line is how i found to solve the "unique items" but it doesn't seem a good practice, can anybody point me what i messed up? Probably it's silly but i can't see.

Thank you all!!

Comment: You are already checking inside the loop to see if values exist. Seems redundant to use both approaches

Comment: In my mind i'd do the first check to see if the input is somewhere in the file and the second to see if i can push to the arrayRes. The last line new_array i added because the indexOf(variable) === -1 don't return me the uniques, that's the question i'm making, did i express myself more clear now? Sorry for the english, not native...